Render a jinja template with ansible variables and store it into a register
I need to a jinja2(.j2) file with variables defined in it like {{ var }}
I was using template module to input variables taken as arguments.
      #Rendering jinja file into SQL file with
    - name: Render SQL file with variable
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "path to j2 file"
        dest: "path to temp file"
      register: sql_file_content
      vars:
              limit: "{{ limiting_input }}"
      delegate_to: localhost


    - name: fetch contents of SQL file
      ansible.builtin.slurp:
            src: "{{ sql_file }}"
      register: sql_file_content
      delegate_to: localhost

But now I want to take the rendered out put directly into the register without using any temp file is there a way to do it?
some thing where I can skip dest: and put formatted file content directly into a register
      #Rendering jinja file into SQL file with
   
    - name: Render SQL file with variable
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: "path to j2 file"
      register: sql_file_content
      vars:
              limit: "{{ limiting_input }}"
      delegate_to: localhost


tried it like this got error
TASK [Render SQL file with variable] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoneType: None
fatal: [IP -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "src and dest are required"}

was expecting it to store the content into the register.
